# in mysql,how to avoid loading the similar data file into table if already exist

Tags: mysql

i am using the following command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/sample.txt' INTO TABLE TEST FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

whenever executed this query ,table "**TEST**" gets added the values from **sample.txt** file.

How to avoid this multiple entries  in table.i want to load this file if table doesn't load this file already.

Comment: add constraint  and indexes on tables for uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

diEcho's comment is nearly right - identify unique column combinations in the data and declare them as a unique  index on the table - but importantly you also need to modify your LOAD DATA statement - as its stands, it will fall over at the first occurrence of a duplicate record. You need to add an IGNORE:

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE '/sample.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE `test` 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Although for preference you should consider loading the full dataset into a staging table then handle the duplicates a bit more gracefully.